# Making perpendicular lines through each polygon edge using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I have polygons and lines I would like to make perpendicular lines through each polygon edge so I can find intersections with other polygons and lines.

[image]

Comment: Did you already tried something? if so please share your attempt so ppl. can help you better. In general, you are supposed to show your effort, when it comes for coding help

Comment: Why not to use http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.htm? Tell more about what kind of features you would like to find?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you have PostGIS knowledge, this is one way forward:

- Take the [ExteriorRing](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ExteriorRing.html) from your polygon (results in a linestring)
- Make seperate segments out of your ExteriorRing (use [this](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/breaking-linestring-into-segments.html) example from Paul Ramsey)
- Create parallel lines with [ST_OffsetCurve](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_OffsetCurve.html) with a desired distance D on the correct side (your polygons vertices should always have the same direction, use [ST_ForceRHR](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ForceRHR.html) when they don't)
- For every segment, make a new line from the [centroid](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Centroid.html) of that segment to the centroid of the corresponding parallel line with [ST_MakeLine](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html)

Now you should have your perpendicular lines with a length D starting from the sides of your polygon.